# How did some English words get a "y" sound in front of "uː"-sounding vowels?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm wondering what mechanism puts a *y* sound (IPA /j/) into words like *coupon*, which presumably had none when it came into the language. French pronunciation would seem to indicate it would be pronounced [ˈkuːpɔ:n], not [ˈkjuːpɔ:n], but many people pronounce it the latter way.

Similarly, why do we have such a difference in a word like *duke*, which can be pronounced [djuːk] or [duːk], when *dude* only ever seems to be pronounced [duːd]?

**addendum**

An even more puzzling example, brought up in the comments below, is that of Houston, which is pronounced with the /j/ when it refers to the city in Texas, and without it when referring to the street in Manhattan.

Comment: I think interpolating a "y" sound into ***coupon*** would be a "hypercorrection". It's not the same as, say, ***duke*** - which Brits (but not all *Americans*) pronounce as **/djuːk/**.

Comment: "Coupon" is "coup" followed by "pon".  (Never mind that the first syllable is really open and there is only one "P" sound.)  "Coup" is like a chicken coup, then tack on the "pon" sound.  "Coupon".

Comment: (There are some in the US, though, who pronounce it "cue-pon".  But ever since the folks on TV started using "coup-pon" back about 1960 that pronunciation has gotten rarer and rarer.)

Comment: Is it a regional thing, like pronouncing _word_ as "woid" in Brooklyn and New Joisey?

Comment: Really, *duke* and *dude* ***should*** have the same vowel. But you hear *duke* in movies where everyone speaks with an upper class British accent, and *dude* in movies where bowlers speak with laid-back California accents. And so these are the pronunciations you use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm just wondering why it would be a hypercorrection, I mean of what? Nothing obvious jumps out at me.

Comment: @HotLicks: I hear it both ways, from people with no agenda about the pronunciation. It seems to be simply unconscious.

Comment: Thanks for using IPA: the non-IPA comments are not useful and should be revised or deleted so people can understand them. The reason you’re hearing them as different because /u/ and /ju/ are phonemically distinct in English: consider the minimal pair *cute* and *coot*. So it is not just allophonic variation. For the record, the French pronunciation would be /kupɔ̃/.

Comment: It's true that /uː/ and /juː/ are separate phonemes in English, but there's historical overlap and therefore confusion. It depends on the preceding consonant, as mentioned above, but it's complicated.  British speakers say 'duke' as [djuːk/ while lots of Americans say /duːk/.  On the other hand, no-one says 'super' as /sjuːpə/ or /sjuːpɹ̩/ anymore, while everyone says 'human' as /hjuːmən/ [unless they drop the H].  This last example may be why Americans say 'Houston' as /hjuːstən/ which sounds odd to us Brits because here, words with 'ou' in the spelling never get the /j/.

Comment: @Robusto: I'm quite familiar with the (primarily American) pronunciation where *due, do* and *tune, 'toon* are homonyms, but I'm not sure I've ever heard anyone use the /j/ version in a word like *coupon* (except maybe facetiously). Because Americans don't actually *have* "dukes", they probably hear the BrE pronunciation relatively more often than we might otherwise expect. Leading perhaps to the idea that our version is more "traditional, correct", which could then *further* lead to erroneously applying "the same" adjustment to other words where there's no historical basis for doing this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: but you'd agree with what I said about Houston [as in Texas, not Houston St., NY?]

Comment: @David Garner: I'm not *that* attuned to AmE! I've only just realised that HOOSTON is primarily an "erroneous" BrE version of the place whose inhabitants all call it HEWSTON. I'm probably like most Brits - I assume that one fits the general pattern, so out of respect for the natives I sometimes pronounce it the way I mistakenly thought they did. [As does the BBC, apparently.](https://mefoley.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/houston-the-bbc-has-a-problem/)

Comment: Regarding Houston: the street in NYC by that name is pronounced to rhyme with "house ton" . . . which makes one wonder where Texas got that pronunciation in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They do have "The Dooks of Hazzard" including Daisy Dook.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for that link -  fascinating.  Two points.  (1) To repeat and expand, in BrE, 'ou' may represent /aʊ/, /əʊ/, /uː/ and a few others, but as far as I can think, never /juː/. When a Brit sees 'ou', the default is /uː/, in the same way that when English-speakers see 'th' in an unfamiliar word, they'll go for /θ/ not /ð/. (2) In the specific case of Houston, I think /huːstən/ took hold in the UK during early space-shots and won't let go now.  It's amazing how often newspapers use it: "Hello, Euston, we have a problem."

Comment: @David Garner: Yeah - but although I can just about believe *s-YOU-per, s-YOU-et, c-YOU-pon* as "facetiously affected upper-class" versions of *super, suet, coupon*, I can't really imagine anyone doing that with, say, *m-YOU-stache*. Anyway, noting ***Tucson***, so far as I'm concerned the name of any particular place in America is essentially what the natives call it (except for oddities like *Houston*, where I guess I must now admit we Brits habitually get it "wrong").

Comment: OK, so what is the correct way to say "Louisville", the major city in the US state of Kentucky?

Comment: @Hot: What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't count me in with the 'habitually wrong Brits' - Houston has always been 'Hyoo-ston' since 'Houston, we've got a problem'.

Comment: @Frank: I honestly don't know if I'm in the *majority* (of Brits), but [***Houston:** Staying on the theme of American place names, the famous Texan city of Houston represents another phonetic role reversal. In words like “tuna”, it is normally the British who incorporate a y-sound even when the letter “y” is absent from the word itself {e.g. TYOO-na}. However, on this occasion, Americans—almost universally—pronounce Houston as “HYOO-stun,” whereas the British very often say “HOO-stun.”*](http://www.bbcamerica.com/mind-the-gap/2014/09/04/10-place-names-brits-americans-pronounce-differently/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Houston is English (or at the very least British). I'd need to check but I'm quite confident that the Irish/Scottish Houstons are why Houston is so-called. (and hence the pronunciation).

Comment: The part of this question relating to the /j/ in "coupon" and "Houston" is not duplicated, but the part relating to "duke" is, by the following question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232729/u-pronounced-ew

Comment: "Dude" is also a newer word, so any regularization that it might undergo could still be in its future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, but perhaps the /ju/, which came by breaking a high front rounded [y] in words borrowed from French, came to be regarded as a high prestige form.  Then, hearing /u/, some English speakers interpreted that as a mistaken or low-class way of saying /ju/ and decided to correct it in their own pronunciations.  If that's right, the /ju/ from earlier /u/ should turn up in words most easily interpreted as having been borrowed from French.  Folk loan phonology.

Comment: The /ju/ came from several places: the action of the Great Vowel Shift on the vowel /y/, which was actually used in Middle English for words of French origin like *duke*, and the action of the Great Vowel Shift on Middle English diphthongs like *dew*, which came from Old English diphthongs. [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_back_vowels#Merger_of_Middle_English_.2Fy.2F.2C_.2F.C9.9Bu.2F.2C_.2Feu.2F.2C_and_.2Fiu.2F), which says that three different diphthongs and the vowel /y/ all got merged into /juː/.