# <u> pronounced "ew"

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, historical-change, great-vowel-shift

I'm wondering about the modern English pronunciation of "u" like the vowel in "few" in open syllables, such as "p*u*re", "c*u*te", "trib*u*nal", "*u*", etc. What's the origin of this?

(This question is **not** about the smoothing of this diphthong in American dialects after a coronal consonant- new, grew, lure, etc.)

ty~

Comment: Note: _grew_ doesn’t have a /j/ in any dialect. Tautosyllabic /rj/ is not allowed in English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did some English words get a "y" sound in front of "uː"-sounding vowels?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229476/how-did-some-english-words-get-a-y-sound-in-front-of-u%cb%90-sounding-vowels)

Comment: @Robusto: It seems to me like there are two related but distinct questions involving this: how did words spelled with "u" like "Duke" come to be pronounced with /juː/, and how did words with "ou" like "coupon" come to be pronounced with /juː/ by at least some speakers. This question only covers the first group. What do you think about editing your question so it only covers the latter? Then neither would be a duplicate.

Comment: @sumelic: So you're saying this duplicate should stand because it only addresses part of the one I mentioned? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's recently come to my attention that Dutch went through a similar process where long <u> is pronounced /y/ because of palatalization (i.e. the vowel moved to a more frontward pronunciation). I wonder if this could be a similar development?

Answer (score 5):

In most cases the pronunciation of u as /ju:/ is an indication that the word is connected with a French word. French u is regulary pronounced as /y/ as in

- French le duc /dyk/ - English duke /dju:/, AmE /du:k/
- F dû/due /dy/ - E due /dju:/
- F la vue /vy/ - E view /vju:/

Also German words with ü become words with /ju:/ in English

- G München - E Munich /'mju:nik/

The letter u has the pronunciation (PN) /ʌ/ as in to cut,
and the PN /ju:/ in open syllables as in cu-te. An open syllable has the 
structure vowel (no consonant); here only the written form is relevant, not the spoken form. A closed syllable has the structure vowel+ consonant.

In American English /ju:/ is  reduced to /u:/ after a certain group of consonants as in

- duke /du:k/
- new /nu:/

In his comment below Peter Shor has enumerated the special consonants after which /ju:/ is reduced to /u:/.

Comment: Saying *"in American English  /ju:/ is regularly reduced to /u:/"* is liable to confuse some non-Americans.  We only do that after certain consonants, most notably  /n/, /d/, /t/, /s/, /l/. We never do it after /b/, /p/,  /k/, /m/, /h/, /f/, /v/ .

Comment: @Peter Shor - Thanks for  the correction. I'll change my formulation accordingly .

Comment: @rogermue the American phenomenon is not at all universal.  There are plenty of Americans who say *duke* as /du:k/ and *new* as /nju:/.  Even those who say /dju:k/are very unlikely to say *sue* as /sju:/.

Comment: Also words that came to us from Anglo Saxon are pronounced neither as /u/ nor /ju/: house, out, etc.  It seems to be that /ju/ is more about when the word with the /u/ vowel entered the language than its source.  It's just that the biggest source of new words at that time was French.

Comment: There are a bunch of different sources for the /ju/ combination. The most common is probably the French /y/, but there are a number of words originating in Old English (for example, [*spew*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=spew)) where a diphthong in Middle English mutated into /ju/.

Answer (score 1):

I specUlate that the "ew" (/ju/) is more common in Southern Regional English. E.g. there are towns in the South spelled with "u" which have the /ju/ sound: Bude, Mississippi, is pronounced like its English namesake, Bude/Bewd, England. Could it be another of those archaic survivals from dialectical isolation in the rural South? (e.g., "Pierre" pronounced as "Per"; "person" as "poisson"; "roasting" as "rowsn"; and the aformentioned "new" as "gnew", a pronunciation quite common in my rural South of the past. Not sure if "shoe"/"shew" is related, for other such words ("hoe", "froe") have a simple long "o" sound.

Comment: Without using IPA or at least a standardized pronunciation notation your examples don’t really help.  How do I know how you pronounce “rowsn”  or “poisson” and what is a porson anyway?

Comment: sorry; corrected tyoe of "porson/person". There is no phonological notation I'm aware of, including IPA or any other, than can accurately represent the pronunciation of "rowss-nears", which is the Southern version of "roasting ears", referring to ears of corn picked at a particular time for the purpose of roasting them in-husk over fire. Even my (mis)representation of its pronunciation is way off. I guess it's an oral thing.